# Spring Boot RDS connection credentials

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-rds

I am working on spring boot microservice for Elastic Beanstalk, and want to clarify how RDS credentials are passing to my application when it is deployed?

Previously I worked with Cloud Foundry and I know that Spring Cloud Connectors library provides dedicated "Cloud" class, which can be used to get instance of DataSource, and there is no need to explicitly specify login/password.

With AWS it seems that I have to explicitly specify credentials in application environment
RDS_HOSTNAME, RDS_USERNAME,RDS_PASSWORD, ...
(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.RDS.html?icmpid=docs_elasticbeanstalk_console)
And I could not found examples that Spring Cloud AWS can do that automatically (in the same way as in CF).

For me it just looks inconvenient, is it a common way for AWS?
Also if RDS instance integrated with application (bound to app lifecycle) environment variables are set automatically, why this can't be done in case of external RDS instance?

Answer (score 1):

Those are the standard environment variables that will be assigned to your Elastic Beanstalk environment if you integrate the RDS instance with your Elastic Beanstalk application. If you don't integrate it, then you simply need to create those (or similar) environment variables in your EB environment using the `eb setenv` command.

Note that this same mechanism an be used for other things than RDS instances. Perhaps you have an external service like a Redis or MongoDB database or some sort of API that your Elastic Beanstalk application needs to access. By creating environment variables you can specify both security credentials and any environment specific endpoints that your application will need.

You just need to use the standard Java/Spring method of accessing system environment variables in order to pull these values into your application.

Comment: Ok, I just thought that RDS binding in AWS might work similar to Cloud Foundry, where I can just bind Database service and get already configured DataSource from Spring Cloud Connectors.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that an RDS is attached to the application in the beanstalk environment, there is an option to define environment variables and their values as well.

Suppose, you configure the application to communicate with the underlying RDS with the help of

```
server.port=xxxx
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${RDS_HOSTNAME}:${RDS_PORT}/${RDS_DB_NAME}
spring.datasource.username=${RDS_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password=${RDS_PASSWORD}
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

One can configure these settings for the use of already spun RDS on RDS and provide the endpoints and credentials here too.